# Whats the difference between NVIDIA third-party free and distro non-free drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, performance

Mostly I focus on better driver performance. Whats the difference?
I have NVIDIA 435 Distro Non-Free driver and NVIDIA 440 Third-party Free driver (recommended) as shown in the screenshot below:
[image]

Which to pick?

Comment: What are "third-party free"? I am not aware of any free drivers except in-tree `nouveau`.

Comment: If you are asking about dirvers from a PPA, they are erroneously displayed as free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the 435 driver from Ubuntu repositories and the 440 from `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` are proprietary Nvidia drivers. None of them are free.

You can pick any of those and test. There shouldn't be much difference.

But the 440 are the latest with some improvements that you can see at [Nvidia site](https://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/156086).